# Bootstrap styling for multilevel dropdown menu with recursive function ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to style this dropdown menu with bootstrap so it would appear a little nicer:

```
<ul id="menu">
    @ShowTree(Model)
</ul>
@helper ShowTree(List<Category> categories)
    {
        foreach (var item in categories)
        {
            <li class="@(item.Children.Any() ? "parent" : "")">
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "", "")
                @if (item.Children.Any())
                {
                    <ul class="child">
                        @ShowTree(item.Children)
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>

        }
    }
```

So basically I'm assigning `class="parent"` if the category has any children and `child` if it has a parent.

Trying to get something like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

My category class:

```
public class Category
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You could send the level in to the method `ShowTree(List<Category> categories, int level)` and then `@ShowTree(item.Children, level + 1)`

Comment: @VDWWD can you show a simple example please?

Comment: I've added an example. You can now use css to style `level_0`, `child_0`, `level_1`, `child_1` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="menu">
    @ShowTree(Model, 0)
</ul>

@helper ShowTree(List<Category> categories, int level)
    {
        foreach (var item in categories)
        {
            <li class="level_@level">
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "", "")
                @if (item.Children.Any())
                {
                    <ul class="child_@level">
                        @ShowTree(item.Children, level + 1)
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>

        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe im dumb, but I'm really not getting this one. What if there are unlimited `<li>` or children? I can't just edit the css if I add one more category in the database.